# How can I use Whatsapp without scanning any QR code?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

My phone is broken, and I need to use Whatsapp. I already tried Whatsapp Web, but it is asking for me to scan a QR code, which I can't. Is there any other way to access my Whatsapp account through my PC with the help of an OTP or something?

Comment: Is your phone completely broken? You need a phone to use whatsapp.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Currently QR code is the only way to access the messages on your PC. The messages never leave your phone, they're merely just displayed on your PC, unlike Telegram or other messengers, where messages are synced online through their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem's solution is genymotion emulator its easy and fast 
Go to this  [link](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) and select download for personal use.
As you said you can get otp, so it will be a perfect solution.

Comment: Can you tell us how to set this up for using Whatsapp?

Comment: It should be normal process, just like setting up whatsapp in a mobile device.

Comment: Can I have Whatsapp on Genymotion and on my phone linked to the same account?

Answer (score -2):

If your phone is broken you can download whatsapp via an android emulator on your pc and use it easily that way.

Comment: Great suggestion! However would have be even more impressive if you gave examples of emulators, download links and brief instructions.

Comment: More importantly, if the questioner's phone is broken, how are they going to get access to their account on an emulator, when accounts are tied to phone numbers?